# Cleanest way to get a concrete type based on input in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I have a method as follows, which is sorta acting like a factory, given a string type, i am returning a concrete type which is implementing IWorkerJob. Is there a better/cleaner way to do this than having a switch statement with 60 cases like these, maybe some sort of lookup?

```
private static IWorkerJob GetWorkerJob(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case WorkerJobType.IMPORT_GOOGLE_JOB:
                return new ImportGoogleJob();
            case WorkerJobType.IMPORT_XYZ_JOB:
                return new ImportXyzJob();

            ....

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think what you have now is fine, really. As long as it's readable. Perhaps another option would be to use Reflection and create the type based on the Enum name, however I'm not sure that's a really "better/cleaner way" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) with `where T : new()` constraint along with `where T : <interface name>`, you can read more about constraints on MSDN article [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

```
private static IWorkerJob GetWorkerJob<T>() where T:IWorkerJob, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a dictionary which maps the `Func` then use it to create the instances.

Something like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IWorkerJob>> workerJobFactories = new Dictionary<string, Func<IWorkerJob>>
{
    {WorkerJobType.IMPORT_GOOGLE_JOB, () => new ImportGoogleJob()},
    {WorkerJobType.IMPORT_XYZ_JOB, () => new ImportXyzJob()}
    ...
};

private static IComparable GetWorkerJob(string type)
{
    Func<IWorkerJob> factory = null;
    if (workerJobFactories.TryGetValue(type, out factory))
    {
        return factory();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also I suggest you to create an `enum` for `WorkerJobType` instead of using strings.